# Conflict with Quicksand

Tags: javascript, jquery, quicksand

I am trying to implement a simple hover effect so when I hover over each project, the description slides in from the right.

So far, I have this set up: http://jsfiddle.net/gnnSB/

In that fiddle, notice that the descriptions don't slide in when you hover over them with the mouse, yet the filtering works well.

Now, take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/gnnSB/1/

Here, the descriptions *do* slide in, but the filtering doesn't work because I took out the Quicksand function (shown below).

I need both of these to work together. There is a conflict and I'm wondering if anybody has experienced anything similar. Is this a simple fix or do I need to resort to another solution?

Quicksand

```
$(function() {

    var time_effect = 400;
    var effect_name = 'easeOutQuart';

    $('.all').quicksand( $('.everything article'), {
        duration: time_effect,
        attribute: 'data-id',
        easing: effect_name,
        adjustHeight: 'auto',
        useScaling: false
      });

    $('.filter-all').click(function(e) {
      $('.all').quicksand( $('.everything article'), {
        duration: time_effect,
        attribute: 'data-id',
        easing: effect_name,
        adjustHeight: 'auto',
        useScaling: false
      });
      $('.filter a').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.filter-web').click(function(e) {
      $('.all').quicksand( $('.web article'), {
        duration: time_effect,
        attribute: 'data-id',
        easing: effect_name,
        adjustHeight: 'auto',
        useScaling: false
      });
      $('.filter a').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.filter-print').click(function(e) {
      $('.all').quicksand( $('.print article'), {
        duration: time_effect,
        attribute: 'data-id',
        easing: effect_name,
        adjustHeight: 'auto',
        useScaling: false
      });
      $('.filter a').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

Hovers

```
$('.thumbnail').hover(function () {
    $('.description', this).stop().animate({
      right: 0
    }, 50);
  }, function () {
    $('.description', this).stop().animate({
      right: -280
    }, 50);
  });
```

Edit: Is there a way to add multiple enhancements? I'm trying to incorporate fancybox.

```
// Fancybox
    var fbox = function() {
                $("a.single-image").fancybox({
                    'transitionIn'   : 'none',
                    'transitionOut'  : 'none',
                    'overlayColor'   : '#000',
                    'overlayOpacity' : '0.6'
                });
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need? **Edit: Refactored** [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/pthYY/8/)

You need to add another config (`enhancement`) for quicksand wherein you'll put the hover functions:

```
enhancement: function() {
              $('.thumbnail').hover(function () {
                    $('.description', this).stop().animate({
                      right: 0
                    }, 50);
                  }, function () {
                    $('.description', this).stop().animate({
                      right: -280
                    }, 50);
                  });
        }
```

Comment: If you mean changing each instance of `$` to `jQuery`, I tried that but there wasn't any difference: http://jsfiddle.net/gnnSB/2/

Comment: Updated answer, my initial thought was that it should be solved by `$.noConflict()`

Comment: Is there a way to add another enhancement by setting up another variable underneath the 'hovers' variable? I'm trying to incorporate fancybox.

Comment: I believe yes, I'll update my answer, since I just got here at work :) Could you fork my fiddle and update with the necessary resources?

Comment: Sure, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/pthYY/9/ I added the fancybox script and some links in the html with a class of `single-image`.

Comment: Try this [http://jsfiddle.net/pthYY/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/pthYY/10/), I added the CSS for fancybox, but upon clicking the link the image doesn't show. I'll refine further when I get home.

Comment: Thank you, I'll wait for the refined version :)

Comment: But try that first, I just tried here at home and I'm getting a cross-domain request error, because the image being used by fancybox is an external resource.

Comment: I just tried it and Fancybox does work; however, the `selected` class applied to the `a` that is currently selected doesn't get applied anymore.

Comment: Ah yes, since `this` being referenced in the `quicksand` function doesn't know what the object really is yet. Just move it inside each `.click` function, updated here [http://jsfiddle.net/pthYY/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/pthYY/11/)